# Get InputStream From a Socket

Tags: java, connection, audio-streaming, sip

I want to stream and audio with SIP Connection in java application(SE).I connected with the server and got 200 OK messages.I want to receive data sent by the server. I created a SOCKET and got an InputStream. Here is how I do it.  *123.456.789.1* is the my ip address and 1234 is which my application listening port.

```
            Socket socket=new Socket("123.456.789.1",1234);                
            InputStream in=socket.getInputStream();
            System.out.println("inputSream available :"+in.available());
```

But in.available() is always 0 .

But if I get the `Object content=response.getContent()`;

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
out.writeObject(content);
byte[] contentBytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

the lenght of contenBytes equals to the response content length.But when I  try to get inputStream and Play ,like following

```
InputStream pp=new ByteArrayInputStream(b);

          AudioStream as = new AudioStream(pp);
          AudioData data = as.getData();
          ContinuousAudioDataStream cas = new ContinuousAudioDataStream (data);
```

An Exception throws;*java.io.IOException: could not create audio stream from input stream* 
Then I tried to read the inputstream `in.read()` then when read some bytes,and IOException was thrown.
Q1. How can I solve and get InputStream from the socket?
Q2. how to get an inputStream to play the audio?

or let me know where the problem is and how to solve it.

**UPDATED:** Thank you all who showed a fault `in.availabe();`
Then I changed the code.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream ou=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
               int i=0;
                System.out.println("Before while");
               while((i=in.read())!=-1){

               ou.write(i);
                   System.out.println("Wrote :"+i);

               }
```

Unfortunately the application doesn't go further.That means only *Before while* is printed.Application just shows running(I use netbeans IDE).I don't why.Any clarification?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What IOException was thrown?

Answer (score 1):

When you use getContent you get some kind of object wrapping the content. Then using an ObjectOutputStream you write the Java representation of that object, not the actual bytes of the original data.

You should be able to do

```
AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in);
AudioData data = as.getData();
ContinuousAudioDataStream cas = new ContinuousAudioDataStream (data);
```

or if you do want to buffer the data

```
int chunkSize;
byte[] chunk = new byte[2048];
ByteArrayOutputStream outBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while ( ( chunkSize = in.read(chunk) ) != -1) {
  outBuffer.write(chunk, 0, chunkSize);
}

ByteArrayInputStream inBuffer = new ByteArrayInputStream(outBuffer.toByteArray());
AudioStream as = new AudioStream(inBuffer);
AudioData data = as.getData();
ContinuousAudioDataStream cas = new ContinuousAudioDataStream (data);
```

*available()* show how many bytes can be guaranteed read before blocking. It might always return 0.

Comment: Thank you Roger. I tried you last code sample(buffer data).But the application doesn't go further after ByteArrayOutputStream object creation.It doesn't go into while :( .Would you take a look at my Socket connection and how I get InputStream.

Comment: The code looks ok. Are you sure the server starts sending the bytes when you connect? Don't you have to initialize (send some info) first?

Comment: Thanks for your attention.In my question I have mentioned also.I can get a inputStream from the response(I use JAINsip).but when that inputStream is read,IOExcepton is thrown for some bytes and can't send the stream to audioStream.In the respons's content length is also 280.I printed the byte values to console.(@ that time I observed that IO exception is thrown when some bytes are read)

Comment: But the response is an URLConnection? If so, then initiation has been done (see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) But you should also be able to do getInputStream on the URLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

available() is the number of bytes which can be read *with out* performing a *blocking* call to the OS.  If you want to know how much data is available you should try to read it and see how much you get.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I tried to read.But application doesn't go further.It stops before the while loop.Is there any other problem in my code?

Comment: If the code stops before you the code you are showing, that means there is a bug in that code.  If you are wondering why read() is blocking its because its waiting for some data.  I suggest you use a background thread if you want to do something else while data is being read.

Comment: Would you think,would it be better if I create the socket connection and run the above code in a Thread?I did so.I created a socket and got an inputstream.and tried to read. still it doesn't go further.

Comment: but when I got the response and response length,it gives a length.Also I got the inputstream though the response's content and when I read it,the size is also same as the response's content length. but when I read that inputStream also,it gives IO Exception for some readings.and then can't pass the Inputstream into the AudioStream.

Comment: `available()` is the number of bytes that can be read *without blocking.* The data may be in the socket receive buffer, so an OS call will be required to read it.